# Create a bezier path using an image's transparency, use for CALayer's shadowPath

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, calayer, shadows, shadowpath

Is there an easy way to use an image's transparency to create a bezier path?

I'm trying to optimize an animation of a number of CALayers. But I get huge slowdowns when I add a drop shadow using the built in CALayer shadowColor, shadowOffset, etc.

One of the tips I've found online is to use the shadowPath property. I would like to use a simplified version of the outline of my image as the shadow path. If I could get the path that CALayer uses to draw the shadow, I could simplify it myself.